# ascx file error in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm trying to render a partial ascx view within another view.

I have the following error however in my ascx file, and after some research I'm still in the dark!:

> Type or namespace definition, or
>   end-of-file expectedend-of-file expected

Here is the code in DinnerForm.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<NerdDinner.Models.Dinner>" %>

<%: Html.ValidationSummary("Please Corrent the Errors and Try Again.") %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>

<table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.EventDate) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EventDate) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EventDate, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, ViewData["countries"] as SelectList)%></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Country, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactPhone) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactPhone) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactPhone, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Latitude) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Latitude) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Latitude, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Longitude) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Longitude) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Longitude, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type ="submit" value="Save" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>
```

And here is an example of how I am using it in a file called create.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<NerdDinner.Models.Dinner>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Host a Dinner
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Host a Dinner</h2>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("DinnerForm"); %>
    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how you have `<% } %>` at the bottom of the `.ascx` file? That is a closing bracket for `<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>` which you seem to have missed out.

**Add**

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
```

**to just below the**

```
<%: Html.ValidationSummary("Please Corrent the Errors and Try Again.") %>
```

**Resulting form**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<NerdDinner.Models.Dinner>" %>

<%: Html.ValidationSummary("Please Corrent the Errors and Try Again.") %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>

<table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.EventDate) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EventDate) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EventDate, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, ViewData["countries"] as SelectList)%></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Country, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactPhone) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactPhone) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactPhone, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Latitude) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Latitude) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Latitude, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Longitude) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Longitude) %></td>
            <td><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Longitude, "*") %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type ="submit" value="Save" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>
```

Comment: thank you, I should have seen that one! I will mark this as the correct answer once the time limit is up :)

Comment: @TaraWalsh - it's not very hard to forget to copy that when you move the code to an ascx file. I just finished the NerdDinner book yesterday so still have a fresh memory of it :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the <% } %> from the bottom of your DinnerForm.ascx.

Comment: That would correct the compilation error, but the ascx is clearly a form, so he needs to open the form at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an unpaired `<% } %>` at the end of your ascx file.

The form is missing. Looks like you omitted:

```
<% using( Html.BeginForm() ) { %>
```

from the top, just before the validation summary.